# How to create channel events using Sawtooth Java SDK?

Tags: java, events, hyperledger-sawtooth

HyperLeger Sawtooth supports subscription to events in the Transaction Processor. However is there a way to create application-specific events in the Transaction Processor something like in Python example here: https://www.jacklllll.xyz/blog/2019/04/08/sawtooth/

```py
ctx.addEvent(
 'agreement/create',
 [['name', 'agreement'],
 ['address', address], 
 ['buyer name', agreement.BuyerName], 
 ['seller name', agreement.SellerName], 
 ['house id', agreement.HouseID], 
 ['creator', signer]],
  null)
```

In the current Sawtooth-Java SDK v0.1.2 the only override is

```java
apply(TpProcessRequest, State)
```

Without the context. However on the documentation here: https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-sdk-java/blob/master/sawtooth-sdk-transaction-processor/src/main/java/sawtooth/sdk/processor/TransactionHandler.java

```java
addEvent(TpProcessRequest, Context)
```

So far I have managed to listen to events `sawtooth/state-delta` however this gives me all state changes of that `tx-family`

```java
import sawtooth.sdk.protobuf.EventSubscription;
import sawtooth.sdk.protobuf.EventFilter;
import sawtooth.sdk.protobuf.ClientEventsSubscribeRequest;
import sawtooth.sdk.protobuf.ClientEventsSubscribeResponse;
import sawtooth.sdk.protobuf.ClientEventsUnsubscribeRequest;
import sawtooth.sdk.protobuf.Message;

EventFilter filter = EventFilter.newBuilder()
                     .setKey("address")
                     .setMatchString(nameSpace.concat(".*"))
                     .setFilterType(EventFilter.FilterType.REGEX_ANY)
                     .build();

EventSubscription subscription = EventSubscription.newBuilder()
                      .setEventType("sawtooth/state-delta")
                      .addFilters(filter)
                      .build();

context = new ZContext();
socket = context.createSocket(ZMQ.DEALER);
socket.connect("tcp://sawtooth-rest:4004");

ClientEventsSubscribeRequest request = ClientEventsSubscribeRequest.newBuilder()
               .addSubscriptions(subscription)
               .build();

message = Message.newBuilder()
          .setCorrelationId("123")
           .setMessageType(Message.MessageType.CLIENT_EVENTS_SUBSCRIBE_REQUEST)
          .setContent(request.toByteString())
          .build();

socket.send(message.toByteArray());
```

Once the `Message.MessageType.CLIENT_EVENTS_SUBSCRIBE_REQUEST` is registered I get messages in a thread loop.

I was hoping that in the TransactionHandler I should be able to `addEvent()` or create some type of event(s) that can then be subscribed using the Java SDK.

Has anyone else tried creating custom events in JAVA on Sawtooth?

Comment: Did anyone find this for Java SDK? I am exactly stuck at this point? No Context available in the apply() method. Though there is a getContextId() in the TpProcessRequest object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of an event being added in Python. Java would be similar.
You add your custom-named event in your Transaction Processor:

`context.add_event(event_type="cookiejar/bake", attributes=[("cookies-baked", amount)])`

See https://github.com/danintel/sawtooth-cookiejar/blob/master/pyprocessor/cookiejar_tp.py#L138

Here are examples of event handlers written in Python and Go:
https://github.com/danintel/sawtooth-cookiejar/tree/master/events
Java would also be similar.  Basically the logic in the event handler is:

1. Subscribe to the events you want to listen to
2. Send the request to the Validator
3. Read and parse the subscription response
4. In a loop, listen to subscribed events in a loop
5. After exiting the loop (if ever), unsubscribe rom events

Comment: my issue is not how to, it was more to do with the current Sawtooth Java SDK v0.1.2. The current implementation of the SDK does not send the ``context`` object instead sends a ``state`` object. Whereas on the Sawtooth SDK Git the source shows the ``context`` object with the interface to ``addEvent()`` that aligns with the other SDK's like Phyton / Go. So am I missing v0.1.3 or v0.1.2 is the latest release and I just have to suck-it-up for now and create my own ZMQ message away from the sawtooth ``context`` and consume it such time as the new Java SDK alines with the current GIT source?

Comment: You can also file a JIRA ticket and report the bug. Better yet, file a PR with the fix.
JIRA: https://jira.hyperledger.org (login or create a Linux Foundation ID to login, and go to "Sawtooth")
PR: File a PR with github at https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-sdk-java

Answer (score 0):

For those who are trying to use the java SDK for event publishing/subscribing - There is no direct API available. Atleast I cound't find it and I am using 1.0 docker images.
So to publish your events you need to publish directly to the sawtooth rest-api server. Need to take care of following:

1. You need a context id which is valid only per request. You get this from request in your apply() method. (Code below). So make sure you publish the event during transaction publishing i.e. during the implementation of apply() method
2. Event structure will be as described in docs [here](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/nightly/1-2/app_developers_guide/about_events.html)
3. If the transaction is successful and block is committed you get the event in event subscriber else it doesn't show up.
4. While creating a subscriber you need to subscribe to the

> sawtooth/block-commit

event and add an additional subscription to your type of event e.g. "myNS/my-event"

Sample Event Publishing code:

```
public void apply(TpProcessRequest request, State state) throws InvalidTransactionException, InternalError {

       ///process your trasaction first

        sawtooth.sdk.messaging.Stream eventStream = new Stream("tcp://localhost:4004"); // make this in the constructor of class NOT here
        List<Attribute> attrList = new ArrayList<>();
        Attribute attrs = Attribute.newBuilder().setKey("someKey").setValue("someValue").build();

        attrList.add(attrs);

        Event appEvent = Event.newBuilder().setEventType("myNS/my-event-type")
                .setData( <some ByteString here>).addAllAttributes(attrList).build();
        TpEventAddRequest addEventRequest = TpEventAddRequest.newBuilder()
                .setContextId(request.getContextId()).setEvent(appEvent).build();
        Future sawtoothSubsFuture = eventStream.send(MessageType.TP_EVENT_ADD_REQUEST, addEventRequest.toByteString());

        try {
            System.out.println(sawtoothSubsFuture.getResult());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

then you subscribe to events as such (inspired from the marketplace samples):

```
try {
            
            
            EventFilter eventFilter = EventFilter.newBuilder().setKey("address")
                    .setMatchString(String.format("^%s.*", "myNamespace"))
                    .setFilterType(FilterType.REGEX_ANY).build();

            //subscribe to sawtooth/block-commit
            EventSubscription deltaSubscription = EventSubscription.newBuilder().setEventType("sawtooth/block-commit")
                    .addFilters(eventFilter)
                    .build();

            EventSubscription mySubscription = EventSubscription.newBuilder().setEventType("myNS/my-event-type")
                    .build(); //no filters added for my events.
            
            ClientEventsSubscribeRequest subsReq = ClientEventsSubscribeRequest.newBuilder()
                    .addLastKnownBlockIds("0000000000000000").addSubscriptions(deltaSubscription).addSubscriptions(mySubscription)
                    .build();

            Future sawtoothSubsFuture = eventStream.send(MessageType.CLIENT_EVENTS_SUBSCRIBE_REQUEST,
                    subsReq.toByteString());

            ClientEventsSubscribeResponse eventSubsResp = ClientEventsSubscribeResponse
                    .parseFrom(sawtoothSubsFuture.getResult());

            System.out.println("eventSubsResp.getStatus() :: " + eventSubsResp.getStatus());
            
             if (eventSubsResp.getStatus().equals(ClientEventsSubscribeResponse.Status.UNKNOWN_BLOCK)) {
                 System.out.println("Unknown block ");
                 // retry connection if this happens by calling this same method
                 
             }
            if(!eventSubsResp.getStatus().equals(ClientEventsSubscribeResponse.Status.OK)) {
                System.out.println("Subscription failed with status " + eventSubsResp.getStatus());
                throw new RuntimeException("cannot connect ");
            } else {
                isActive = true;
                System.out.println("Making active ");
            }
            
            
            while(isActive) {
                Message eventMsg =  eventStream.receive();
                EventList eventList = EventList.parseFrom(eventMsg.getContent());
                for (Event event : eventList.getEventsList()) {                 
                    System.out.println("An event ::::");
                    System.out.println(event);
                }
                
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```